# Xcode open Mail app without mailto: property

Tags: objective-c, email, url, mailto

I have a question about opening the Mail application on a iOS device. I want to open the Mail application from my app so that the user can choose a specific file to open it in my application. I have tried with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:"]];
```

but the problem is that I don't want that the user is redirected to a compose view.

Any idea?

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I want to open the Mail App without composing a new message, but with just entering to the App...

Comment: Yes, I think the question I linked to is asking the same thing. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: I agree with the @woz, its an exact duplicate. The poser of that question also wants to open the Mail app without showing the composer.